# Where should I keep my constants in lumen?

Tags: php, constants, lumen, error-code

I am writing a web service using Lumen and need to store some constants, specifically error values, but also other configuration parameters. Where would it be most appropriate to put these?

Comment: https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/configuration

All of the configuration options for the Lumen framework are stored in the .env file.

Comment: Or you can create a Config class and then define the static variables

Comment: I don't mean the configuration for lumen but for my web service. I want my error codes in a separate file. Regarding your second comment this is an option, but I'm not sure where to put these classes. Ideally it would just be global define statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I did it.

I made a const.php file within bootstrap folder where I have defined some error codes.

```
<?php
define('VALIDATION_EXCEPTION',422);
```

I included the const.php file in app.php using require_once.

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'./const.php';
```

Now I can call VALIDATION_EXCEPTION from anywhere. for instance.

```
$router->get('/test',function(){
return VALIDATION_EXCEPTION;
});
```

That's it!

Answer (score 3):

This solution was from [this link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/lumen/whats-the-best-place-to-store-the-constants-variables-in-lumen)

.env is intended for per-environment configuration and sensitive credentials.

You can maintain a config with this type of data. There is no default config for Lumen like there is for Laravel, so you need to add the required config directory, and tell Lumen to use it:

```
$ mkdir config
$ touch config/app.php
```

In the app.php file, you can return an array with the config:

```
// config/app.php
<?php
return [
   'order_by' => 'whatever'
   // and so on
];
```

Then tell Lumen to load the config from app.php inside bootstrap/app.php, by adding (after $app has been initialised):

```
$app->configure('app');
```

Finally, you can use the config() helper method to get the configuration:

```
config('app.order_by') // whatever
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a file constants.php inside config/ and put your settings in an array:

```
<?php

return [
    'CONTACT_NAME' => 'Admin'
];
```

Then in your controllers you can get the value by using Config Facade:

```
echo Config::get('constants.CONTACT_NAME');
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would be the correct answer if we were talking about Laravel. But Lumen doesn't come with a config folder. I could create one but I doubt it will work.

Comment: You can create and it should work because lumen follows laravel structure.

Comment: I tried, it doesn't. The facade doesn't exist. I can access a configuration object using app('config') but it doesn't contain any of the constants I defined in /config/errors.php

Comment: Which version you are using because it is the same issue which is discussed in official GitHub https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/107

Comment: composer.json says 5.6.* I'm trying to find out what the * is but none of the files I've checked so far have any version number in the comments. I'll keep looking. But it's pretty much the latest i think. I just followed the standard install procedure a week ago. Did this use to work and has broken recently? You should eventually edit your answer so I can in good faith award you the points for it.

Answer (score 1):

1.Create New Directory Helpers under App Directory.

2.Create New php file ErrorCodes.php under Helpers directory

3.Put your constants in that file

```
<?php define('VALIDATION_ERROR', 'E001'); define('EXCEPTION', 'E002'); define('CUSTOM','E003'); ?>
```

4.Add this ErrorCodes file under autoload section of composer.json

```
"files" : [
        "app/Helpers/ErrorCodes.php"
    ]
```

5.Run composer autoload command in your artisan terminal

```
composer dumpautoload
```

And you are all set to use your constants anywhere in your lumen App.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are talking about two different things here. For configuration values the only correct location is the `.env` file (as already mentioned in the comments).

> https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration#environment-configuration

This is where you put all *environmental specific configuration values* (e.g. API keys, debug mode, etc. etc.). If you have a strong wish for it you can put the env-variables into constants during the bootstrap process e.g.:

```
define('APP_DEBUG',env('APP_DEBUG', true));
```

For defining simple constants there should be multiple possibiilties.

You could do this either *during the bootstrap process* or define *a class (e.g. a model)*:

```
class Error
{
    const FATAL = 1;
    const WARNING = 2;
}


use Error;

....
Error::FATAL;
...
```